# MySQL select_expr used to display only a portion of a record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am importing .csv file contents into a Mysql DB and one of the records Im displaying from the table is 'name', but the client wants to display the first name of the customer only. Here is the current format of 'name' coming from the .csv file:

,"SMITH, DEB",

I can easily extract and display the entire name, but what ***select_expr*** would I use to only extract the first name (DEB in the above example)?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a column with this type of  values `"SMITH, DEB"`? Or do you want to filter on import?

Comment: No I already have the column set up with the correct data type.I need the operation to be done via the query and not during the import.

Comment: It would be better to have two columns and store the first name separately. You can get your firstname with `SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX('SMITH, DEB', ',', -1));` see [MySQL manual, function SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: @VMai Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to have two columns and store the first name separately. You can get your firstname with

```
SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX('SMITH, DEB', ',', -1));
```

SUBSTRING_INDEX with -1 as last parameter takes the part after the last comma. With LTRIM can you remove the leading blank.

see [MySQL manual, function SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

So you can use

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    LTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ',', -1)) AS firstname
FROM 
    managers 
WHERE 
    account_manager_id = '$account_manager_id'
```

and have the first name in an additional column `firstname`

Comment: Im not seeing any examples of how/where to to add it. Here is my existing query: "SELECT * FROM managers WHERE account_manager_id = '$account_manager_id'"

Comment: @TechnoCripple: You've got to add the expression to your field list. I will edit my answer how to do that.